# Many-to-many with exposed join table via code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many

Here's a relationship diagram from a Microsoft Access database:

[image]

Note that there is only one "Nodes" table. "Nodes_1" is not a separate table. Access uses that naming convention when multiple instances of a table are in a relationship diagram.

I'd like to use Entity Framework code-first to define a similar database.

I've started to sketch out the code:

```
namespace Relationships
{
    public class Node
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public virtual ObservableCollection<Relationship> Outgoing { get; set; }
        public virtual ObservableCollection<Relationship> Incoming { get; set; }
    }

    public class Label
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

    public class Relationship
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Node A { get; set; }
        public Node B { get; set; }
        public Label Label { get; set; }
    }

    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Label> Labels { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Relationship> Relationships { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`Outgoing` of a given `Node` should return relationships where that node is the `A`. `Incoming` of a given `Node` should return relationships where that node is the `B`.

What's a good way to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `InverseProperty` annotations to `Outgoing` and `Incoming` seems to have done the trick:

```
public class Node
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("A")]
    public virtual ObservableCollection<Relationship> Outgoing { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("B")]
    public virtual ObservableCollection<Relationship> Incoming { get; set; }
}
```